# How to add more field in joined table "belongsToMany" in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two table in sequelize

1. Warehouse
2. ProductItem

Then I want to create a joined table name Inventory(productionItemId, warehouseId, qty)
and Here is my current code:

```
Warehouse.belongsToMany(ProductItem, {
      as: "productItems",
      through: "inventories",
    });

ProductItem.belongsToMany(models.Warehouse, {
      as: "warehouses",
      through: "inventories",
    });
```

The above code only create a joined table inventories(productionItemId,warehouseId). I would like to know how we can add extra field in inventories such as qty and so on.
Appreciated for your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [BelongsToMany in the official doc](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

Quote:

If you want additional attributes in your join table, you can define a model for the join table in sequelize, before you define the association, and then tell sequelize that it should use that model for joining, instead of creating a new one:

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'user' })
class Project extends Model {}
Project.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'project' })
class UserProjects extends Model {}
UserProjects.init({
  status: DataTypes.STRING
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'userProjects' })

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProjects })
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserProjects })
```

To add a new project to a user and set its status, you pass extra options.through to the setter, which contains the attributes for the join table

```
user.addProject(project, { through: { status: 'started' }})
```